# bing maps, looking for a nearby place

Tags: c#, google-maps, windows-phone-8.1, maps, bing-maps

I'm writing application on WP 8.1 in c# and xaml that should return shops that are in some specific radius from owner of the phone. And as I looked through web I found something like points of interest but it only works for North America, I also found some out-of-date ways, but nothing works for now.
I tried this:

```
string uriToLaunch = @"bingmaps:?&lvl=13&q={nameOfShop}&where={city}" 
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

but it forces me to open new app and I would prefer putting pins on Map Control
but if there is no other way, is it possible to get a list of found places from this quote to bing maps? 
I also tried connecting to google maps api as it has perfect option for this, I checked it from the browser and it worked just fine, but from the application it failes:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new     
 MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // HTTP GET
            String uri = "maps/api/place/search/json?key={MyKey}&location="
                         + position.Coordinate.Latitude 
                         + "," 
                         + position.Coordinate.Longitude +
                         "&radius=500&keyword={nameOfSho}&sensor=true";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                String content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

I used key for web request, is it correct? There is no specific key for Windows Phone.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps has two REST services for getting point of interest data. The first is the NAVTEQ data sources in the Bing Spatial Data Services. These include data for North America and Europe. Here is some information on this service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478189.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757509.aspx

I also wrote a free ebook on creating spatial apps for Windows 8. In there is some good information on how to use this service. You can download a copy of the book here: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

The other service is a legacy SOAP based web service. It includes some data in a lot more countries. You can find documentation on this here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448599.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx